# Oracle 8i select query from multi row dataset with same ID but different status

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

I have been trying to write the correct query to get me the correct results and hours later still no luck. I feel I'm close but I ran out of tricks...

Take a look at this screen shot for example:

[image: Example]

The highlighted data-set is what I'm looking for. So I have many SAMPLE_ID but I want the status for all the rows to be 'S'. You see the not highlighted data-set has mixes statuses including 'S'. Now my issue is, I still get those ones...

Here is my query:

```
SELECT T3.SAMPLE_ID FROM 
LIMSFD_SAMPLE_INFO T3
WHERE T3.SAMPLE_ID IN
(SELECT SAMPLE_ID FROM LIMS_FINAL_RESULT WHERE SECTION_ID = 'FD' AND STATUS = 'S' )
AND T3.SAMPLE_ID NOT IN
(SELECT SAMPLE_ID FROM LIMS_FINAL_RESULT WHERE SECTION_ID = 'FD' AND STATUS != 'S' )
```

So the first sub-query gets the results with 'S' status and the second sub-query gets the results with anything but 'S' status and using "IN" and "NOT IN", I figured it would filter out the unwanted results.

Now, since this is Oracle 8i, the more sub-queries I introduce the more it is slow. I tried this one here and it crashed the explorer:

```
SELECT T3.SAMPLE_ID FROM 
LIMSFD_SAMPLE_INFO T3, 
LIMSFD_SAMPLE_INFO T4
WHERE T3.SAMPLE_ID IN
(SELECT SAMPLE_ID FROM LIMS_FINAL_RESULT WHERE SECTION_ID = 'FD' AND STATUS = 'S' )
AND T4.SAMPLE_ID NOT IN
(SELECT SAMPLE_ID FROM LIMS_FINAL_RESULT WHERE SECTION_ID = 'FD' AND STATUS != 'S' )
AND T3.SAMPLE_ID <> T4.SAMPLE_ID
```

Can someone point me in some direction to go about this issue?
So from the image above, I should get only the highlighted rows and none of the other ones... In my queries, I get both.

Many thanks!

Comment: @halfer - Haha! Sorry I wasn't shouting but it was probably out of frustration with this DB. I should've added that I am migrating everything to MariaDB but that'll take some time...

Comment: Oracle 8i - seriously?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Do you have a useful answer? Lol

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit we moved to MySQL on December 1st and I couldn't be happier :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I found the answer! I don't know how I didn't come across the MINUS operator before.

So my new query get's me exactly what I was looking for. Here is the updated query:

```
select sample_id
from limsfd_sample_info
where sample_id in
(select sample_id from lims_final_result
where sample_type = 'OF' and analyte_code != 99 and section_id = 'FD' and status = 'S')
minus
select sample_id
from limsfd_sample_info
where sample_id in
(select sample_id from lims_final_result
where sample_type = 'OF' and analyte_code != 99 and section_id = 'FD' and status != 'S')
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!! If you have Oracle 8i and looking to migrate, keep an eye I will post a thread about it... It will make your applications lightning fast :D

I can't wait................... NOT!!!